# How do i properly implement CefSharp in my wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I've been trying to get CefSharp working with WPF (.NET Core) and every time I try it, it always gives me this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The error occurs here:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); <-
        }  
    }
```

and here is the XAML file

```
    <Window x:Class="testwpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="625">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"
        Address="https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore.csproj#L19 for an example of the changes required.

Comment: can you specify where to put the code in the minimal example @amaitland ? I'm a beginner so if this is a stupid question i'm sorry

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You need to modify the project file,  for which I've linked an actual example.

Comment: yea nvm im dumb sorry for wasting your time lol